# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un contador de el tiempo de métodos o funciones que demoran en ejecutarse en C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, time

Hola amigos disculpen la pregunta, pero les comento mi problema, soy nuevo en C# y se me encargo realizar un contador de procesos y mostrar en pantalla cuanto demora un proceso en ejecutarse, la verdad estoy perdido decirles si por favor supieran puedan recomendar una librería en `ASP.net CORE` o alguna librería algún código para reutilizar.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer uso de `System.Diagnostics`

```
var reloj= System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

// Aquí va el código que quieres  medir

reloj.Stop();
var TiempoEnMilisegundos= watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```